# connected DHCP clients to a Router in java

Tags: java, ip, router, dhcp

To get the connected devices' ip address, I applied below approach

1. Ping(ICMP) ip addresses.

Example : (192.168.0.1 to 255 with time limit 5000ms).
If device will not respond in 5000ms then it will drop the IP.

1. For dropped IP addresses; find the http port(80) accessibility on that IP address.(But this failed again bcz of firewall).

I downloaded utilities like IPScanner but this is also showing the same ip addresses as i am getting in my java code.

Is there any way to ping by going through firewall?

**Edited:**

I am using this code(ICMP) to ping,

```
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { (byte) 192, (byte) 168, 1,(byte)1   });
                        System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + inet);
                        System.out.println(inet.isReachable(10000) ? "Host is reachable": "");
```

and if a IP is not reachable then I try to find its open HTTP port 80 by this code,

```
 HttpURLConnection urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
        urlcon.connect();   
        if (urlcon.getResponseCode() == 200) 
        {   
           System.out.println("Connected");
        }
```

Comment: Reconfigure Firewall.
Btw are u sure that is firewall problem? Maybe you try to ping address belonging to another vLan for example?

Comment: I am trying to find dhcp client list in my java code; as shown in router webUI.I am getting exception provided in below link; on this basis am telling this firewall problem. and I can not reconfigure fiewall bcz there are android devices too in this network

Comment: Yeah router see everything, as I said you can only ping devices in your vLan / subnetmask space.

Comment: Is there any way to get same list in my code?

Comment: I dont see your code post it and I tell you

Comment: @dharr, please take a look.